# How to handle "refresh token is not available"?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I know this question has been asked a few times before, but either their answers are wrong or don't work for my workflow.

Within my app, users can go to their settings page and authorize my app to manage their calendars. The Google API then provides me an "access token" which I save in my database with the rest of their user info.

Now users can create events within my app. When they create an event, I want to save a copy to Google Calendar. To do that, I use this handy method I wrote to get a `Google_Client`:

```
public static function getClient(User $user=null) {
    if(!$user) $user = Auth::user();

    $api = new Google_Client();
    $api->setApplicationName("MyWebApp");
    $api->setScopes([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR]);
    $api->setClientId(Config::get('gapi.web.client_id'));
    $api->setClientSecret(Config::get('gapi.web.client_secret'));
    $api->setRedirectUri(URL::route('gapi.oauth2callback'));
    $api->setAccessType('offline');

    if(strlen($user->gapi_access_token)) {
        $api->setAccessToken($user->gapi_access_token);

        if($api->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $refreshToken = $api->getRefreshToken();
            if(strlen($refreshToken)) {
                $api->refreshToken($refreshToken);
                $user->gapi_access_token = $api->getAccessToken();
                $user->save();
            } else {
                // what should we do now?
            }
        }
    }

    return $api;
}
```

The problem is that even if the user has an access token, it's possible that it's expired *and unrefreshable*. The specific error message I get is:

> The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.

This scenario is easy enough to detect with another call to `googleClient->isAccessTokenExpired()`, and then I *could* forward the user off to `$googleClient->createAuthUrl()` which just auto-authenticates anyway because they've already authorized my app -- the problem is that I can't set a dynamic return URL!

I want to complete the action of creating the event as soon as the user re-authenticates, but I'm not allowed to pass along any GET params in the redirect URI so I have no idea what the user was trying to do before they left my site.

How do I handle this? Why do I have to keep forwarding users away from my site after they've already given me permission?

Comment: I've just noticed I haven't actually received a `refresh_token` despite using access type = offline and approval prompt = force.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using access_type=offline when you are authenticating the user (Making him go through OAuth2 cycle). Also check your Google Developer Console and make sure that you've selected "Web Application" while creating Credentials on the console. Check the access_token received on user's completion of OAuth cycle, whether that contains refresh_token or not.

Comment: I had access_type=offline, and I've selected is a Web Application. I think it might be because I tried authenticating myself more than once, and the 2nd+ time it was auto-approved. And auto-approved auths don't contain a refresh token. I'm hoping approval_prompt=force will fix this but I guess I have to wait and see.